# Override / Extend behat ProgressStepPrinter

Tags: php, behat

I am trying to create an extension to behat [progress output step formatter](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/master/src/Behat/Behat/Output/Node/Printer/Progress/ProgressStepPrinter.php).

The goal is simply change the `.` to a `*` for each passed scenario step.

[The behat documentation](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html) does not even mention the ability to create a custom formatter, however I found a GitHub repository that does this [behat-format-progress-fail](https://github.com/integratedexperts/behat-format-progress-fail)

But no clear / simple overview of how to achieve this is there, I have tried duplicating and modifying them.  Is there a simple example or clear documentation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a very cut down version of `ProgressStepPrinter.php` and then including that in `autoload-dev` in `composer.json` uses it in prefernce to the one from `Behat`.

ProgressStepPrinter.php

```
namespace Behat\Behat\Output\Node\Printer\Progress;

use Behat\Behat\Output\Node\Printer\Helper\ResultToStringConverter;
use Behat\Behat\Output\Node\Printer\StepPrinter;
use Behat\Behat\Tester\Result\StepResult;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioLikeInterface as Scenario;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode;
use Behat\Testwork\Output\Formatter;

final class ProgressStepPrinter implements StepPrinter {

    private $resultConverter;

    public function __construct(ResultToStringConverter $resultConverter) {
        $this->resultConverter = $resultConverter;
    }

    public function printStep(Formatter $formatter, Scenario $scenario, StepNode $step, StepResult $result) {
        //custom logic to print per step here
    }
}
```

composer.json

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "files": [
        "features/bootstrap/ProgressStepPrinter.php",
    ]
},
```